# Pumping Lemma for $\mathcal{L} = \{ \omega \omega^R a^{|\omega|} : \omega \in \{a,b\}^* \} $

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I have to show that this language is not context free $\mathcal{L} = \{ \omega \omega^R a^{|\omega|} : \omega \in  \{a,b\}^* \} $, where the $R$ corresponds to the reverse. For this I will use the pumping motto for free context languages. I know how it works, but I have problems choosing the correct $ \sigma $, because when looking at the alternatives for $ vwx $, knowing that $ uv^kwx^kz$ has to be met, I can't get to something concrete, the $a^{| \omega |}$ makes me sick. Is there any other way to show that it is not context free? or that $ \sigma $ could occupy.

Comment: What is $\sigma$? Please consider the fact that notations for the pumping lemma are not necessarily universal.

Comment: Please do not delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but also to others in the future.  Deleting your question after receiving an answer can be considered impolite to answerers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not very hard if you break the proof of the pumped string not being in the language into cases. So let's work this out.
$$L = \{\omega \omega^Ra^{|\omega|}\;| \; \omega\in \{a,b\}^*\}$$

For every $n$, let us consider the string $\omega = a^nb^nb^na^na^{2n}$. You can check that this does belong to the language.

We are supposed to show that for any partition $\omega=uvwxy$, such that
$$|vwx|\leq n \;\mbox{and} \; |vx|\geq 1$$ there exists $k$ such that $uv^kwx^ky \notin L$.

**Case1:** $v,x$ lie inside the first $a^n$. Since, $|vx|\geq 1$, we can see that for $k=0$, the resulting string will not be in $L$.

**Case2:** $v,x$ lie in the starting $a^nb^n$. You should notice that if you again pump the substrings with $k=0$, then the substring cannot be broken into $\omega\omega^R a^{|\omega|}$, because the count of $a$'s at the end remains the same, and we cannot have an $\omega$ of length $2n$ in the resultant string for it to happen.

**Case3:** $v,x$ lie inside the first $b^n$. Here, again, you can see how $k=0$ will pump the string outside the language.

The further cases are similar to what described above. Work it out for better understanding. Please let me know if you aren't comfortable with any part of this solution.

PS: The $a^{|\omega|}$ which makes you sick was the sole reason this language is not a CFL, XD.